# Video capture, Processing missing device

Tags: device, video-capture, processing

I have a video capture device via USB for mac, that i want to use in Processing.
The device shows up in the USB Prober and I have additional info from the IORegistryExplorer if needed.
In Processing, the available devices array lists as follows:

```
0 DV Video
1 ECVComponent
2 Google Camera Adapter 0
3 Google Camera Adapter 1
4 IIDC FireWire Video
5 USB Video Class Video
6 VideoGlide
```

While 4 and 5 launch the capture.settings window as well as iSight (internal webcam), the others merely turn on the light next to the camera but with no apparent signal/ grey window.

In the capture.settings() window, however, all sources in the list are greyed out except for number 5, which lists as 'Built-in iSight', even with number 4 chosen as device in the code.

The console on the other devices read something like

```
quicktime.std.StdQTException[QTJava:7.7.1g],-9408=deviceCantMeetRequest,QT.vers:7718000
    at quicktime.std.StdQTException.checkError(StdQTException.java:40)
    at quicktime.std.sg.SGChannel.setDevice(SGChannel.java:330)
    at processing.video.Capture.init(Capture.java:203)
    at processing.video.Capture.(Capture.java:154)
    at sketch_nov30a.setup(sketch_nov30a.java:36)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1608)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while setting up Capture
    at processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:2571)
    at processing.core.PApplet.die(PApplet.java:2580)
    at processing.video.Capture.init(Capture.java:244)
    at processing.video.Capture.(Capture.java:154)
    at sketch_nov30a.setup(sketch_nov30a.java:36)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:1608)
    at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:1530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

............exiting with

```
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11ed170, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11ec3b0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f4a60, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11ea230
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x1183420, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11e6b60
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f7890, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f7870
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x1fb7b0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x1f47f0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f7a90, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f76e0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f6cf0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11ea040
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f8420, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f7ff0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f6cf0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x1183510
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x148300, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x145720
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x144ec0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x149b40
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f1a20, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f5f80
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f1a20, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11ebd80
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x142ac0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x1a6190
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x158ec0, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x15d000
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f3870, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x1187360
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x14e490, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x19b260
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f6a70, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f6dd0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f3550, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x118f400
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11f5d70, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f3560
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11e3950, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x11f43f0
DVFreeThread - CFMachPortCreateWithPort hack = 0x11ea000, fPowerNotifyPort= 0x118ef60
```

Now, is there maybe a driver for osx, that I'm missing?
The software that came with the capture device shows the received image nicely, - does it matter if the software is running at the same time?

Any help as to what I'm missing and best capture practices i.r.t. Processing is greatly appreciated as well as any (open source) video capturing info.

All the best,
Themapplz

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, as I'm still using osx 10.6.8 and don't have the Elgato video capture device, but I do remember having issues with extra cameras and Processing on OSX.

I simply wanted to use a basic webcam, but didn't have the official osx driver, so couldn't use in Processing by default. I did install the [Macam driver](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/) and that worked for my basic camera. I'm suspecting it might be a driver related issue. 
I had a look at the official Elgator Video Capture website and on their [driver downloads](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/support/Update-Start/Windows-Elgato-Video-Capture.en.html) page it looks like the drivers are for Windows only, although it's advertised to [work on OSX](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product3.en.html) as well. Do the OSX drivers come on the CD only ?